# PowerShell: pass command line parameter from main script to second script

Tags: parameter-passing, powershell-5.0

I have two PowerShell scripts. First script takes two parameters from the command-line and passes them to the second script.

`Script1.ps1`:

```bsh
Write-Output ($args)  
Write-Output ($args.Length)
. ./Script2.ps1 $args
```

`Script2.ps1`:

```bsh
Write-Output ($args)
Write-Output ($args.Length)
```

Calling this like

```bsh
Script1.ps1 hi script1
```

Output of `Script1.ps1`:

```
hi
script1
2
```

Output of `Script2.ps1`:

```
System.Object[]
1
```

**Questions:**

1. Why can't I use `$args` directly on `Script2.ps1` (comes as null)?
2. Why does `$args` passed though `Script1.ps1` come as a single string in `Script2.ps1`?

This works fine in PowerShell 2.0.

Comment: I don't understand your first question. What do you mean by "use `$args` directly on `Script2.ps1`"?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers , just wondering if i can use ```$args``` in ```Script2.ps1``` without been passed from ```Script1.ps1```

Comment: No. `$args` is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) that PowerShell populates with the arguments to a script. And even if you could it would be a bad idea to pass information via global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're invoking the second script from within PowerShell. Because of that the array `$args` is not expanded to its elements, but passed as a single array argument. Use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) to have PowerShell pass the array elements as individual arguments.

```bsh
.\Script2.ps1 @args
```

Side note: using the dot-sourcing operator (`.`) for invoking the script is not required unless you need the script to run in the same context as the script from which it's invoked.